# CUDA, GPU Compute Textures Missing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I recently downloaded the latest NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 8.0 and I also have the latest update of GeForce installed on my computer. I am trying to render my frames on the graphics card, but it doesn't seem to be working. No error shows up. The textures show up in my material and texture view, but not in the final render itself.

Please Help.

Comment: What makes you think this is CUDA related? If you switch to CPU rendering, are the textures still missing?

Comment: I am still relatively new to blender, it seems to be fine on the CPU rendering. I was told that using the Compute will make it run faster.

Comment: That'd true, GPU rendering is (almost) always faster. I've never heard of CPU and GPU renders ever being different though. GPU usually works or doesn't.. Not partially. Sorry, not much help.

Comment: No problem thank you for trying. I am yet to figure it out. If I do I'll definitely leave a post.